# How to add SubItems from ListBox to ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox

Each item in listbox are seperated on the comma. By splitting each line of the listBox i can add only the last items (e.g. STEVEN, D,E,F) but not the other items from the listbox  to the ListView

[image: Figure lb1]

How can this be solved?

```
foreach (string item in listBox2.Items)
{
  ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem();
  var a = item.Split(',');
  li.Text = a[0].Trim();
  li.SubItems.Add(a[1].Trim());
  li.SubItems.Add(a[2].Trim());
  li.SubItems.Add(a[3].Trim());
  listView1.Items.Add(li);
}
```

Comment: It is an Object Oriented World anymore and objects make tasks like this very simple.  Rather than splitting up strings, a DataGridView could use the same DataSource (assuming Winforms).  The ListView is a suboptimal choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the [*ListView*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.8) this way you should set its [*View*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view?view=netframework-4.8) property to [*Details*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.view?view=netframework-4.8) and add [*Columns*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.columns?view=netframework-4.8) to display each string item after doing the split. You can't use your code since the split returns unequal string arrays. Instead, You could do:

```
foreach (string a in ListBox1.Items)
{
    var arr = a.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');

    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(arr[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < arr.Length;i++)
    {
        if(i >= ListView1.Columns.Count )
        {
            ListView1.Columns.Add($"Column {i}");
        }
        lvi.SubItems.Add(arr[i]);
    }
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. It works great!!! Thank you very much!